# Templates, no matching function for call to error

Tags: c++, function, templates, operators

I've made a code which works just fine but one line. It causes me problems. On the line where it says `k = Money<double>().increment (k,m); // this should've printed 6.25` it just doesn't work. When you comment it out and run the code... everything works just fine. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

The error in the console says:

> main.cpp:59:36: error: 'Money::increment(Money&, Money&)' no matching function for call to error 
>   main.cpp:59:36: info: candidate is:
>   main.cpp:41:3: info: T Money::increment(T, T) [with T = double]
>   main.cpp:41:3: info:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Money' to 'double'

And well... candidate is empty too.
As I said without that line everything works just perfect.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Money {
  private:
    T dollar, cent;
  public:
    Money(T a, T b){
        dollar = a;
        cent = b;
    }

  Money(){
    dollar = 0;
    cent = 1;
  }

  Money& operator +=(const Money& v){
    dollar += v.dollar;
    cent += v.cent;
    return (*this);
  }

  Money operator +(const Money& v) const{
    Money temp(*this);
    temp += v;
    return temp;
  }

  Money& operator =(const Money& v){
    dollar = v.dollar;
    cent = v.cent;
    return (*this);
  }

  T increment(T value, T amount);
};

template <class T>
T Money<T>::increment(T value, T amount)
{
  T result = 0;
  result += value + amount;
  cout << result << " $" << endl;
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  double b = 3.45;

  Money<double> k(3,75);
  Money<double> m(2,50);

  a = Money<double>().increment (a,5); // this prints 7
  b = Money<double>().increment (b,4.5); // this prints 7.95
  k = Money<double>().increment (k,m); // this should've printed 6.25
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I'm not sure tracking money as a `double` number of dollars *and* a `double` number of cents is a good idea. It seems like the worse of both worlds.

Comment: So `increment` is little more than something you already have - `+`. I don't see its purpose. It's just as easy to do `printMoney(a + 5)`, which doesn't hide the output (and FWIW, there's a standard `std::put_money` to format currency, so even `printMoney` is unnecessary). You also need a `Money` object in order to use `increment` despite not even using that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T` in the context of a `Money<double>` is `double` but you are not passing `double`s to `Money<double>::increment()`, you are passing `Money<double>` instances, and there is no implicit conversion available from `Money<double>` to `double`.

There are a few ways you could fix this.

- You could create a conversion operator `Money<T>::operator T() const;`. This will provide an implicit conversion from `Money<double>` to `double`, and you can define what it does. The compiler will call this operator automatically on both `Money<double>` instances that you pass.
- You could add an overload for `Money<T>::increment(Money const &, Money const &);`.
- You could have `Money<T>::increment` be itself a template function.

It's not clear from your code exactly which approach you should take, but one of them will resolve this particular error.

Comment: I'm relatively new to C++ and honestly have no idea how to apply the first one. I'm pretty sure this will solve the issue. Do you have any spare time to teach me how to do it?

Comment: @TKD. Add the definition of the operator to the class definition: `operator T() const { /* return a value of type T from here */ }`. Exactly what value you need to return is on you to figure out, but that's the basic template. So for `Money<double>`, this operator will provide an implicit conversion to `double`. [Further reading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by @cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686749/434551) already address the problem in your post.

This answer questions the semantics of the function `increment`.

You are using:

```
a = Money<double>().increment (a,5);
```

That's no different than

```
a += 5;
```

The `Money<double>()` object serves no purpose at all. It does not *increment* any `Money` object. That's why it makes no sense for it to be a member function of the class. To *increment* a `Money` object, one can thing of the following syntax:

```
int a = 2;
double b = 3.45;

Money<double> k(3,75);
Money<double> m(2,50);
Money<double> n(4,20);

k += a;         // Increment k.dollars by a
m += k;         // Increment m by k
m += b;         // Increment m.dollars by b
k.increment(n); // Increment k by n
```

Although I don't know why you would want to use `k.increment(n)` when you can use `k += n`.

Here's a revised version of your class, with a working `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Money {
   private:
      T dollar, cent;
   public:

      Money(T a = {}, T b = {}) : dollar(a), cent(b) {}

      Money& operator +=(const Money& v){
         dollar += v.dollar;
         cent += v.cent;
         return (*this);
      }

      Money operator +(const Money& v) const{
         Money temp(*this);
         temp += v;
         return temp;
      }

      Money& operator =(const Money& v){
         dollar = v.dollar;
         cent = v.cent;
         return (*this);
      }

      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Money const& m)
      {
         return (out << "Dollors: " << m.dollar << ", Cents: " << m.cent);
      }

};

int main()
{
   int a = 2;
   double b = 3.45;

   Money<double> k(3,75);
   Money<double> m(2,50);
   Money<double> n(4,20);

   k += a; // Increment k.dollars by a
   m += k; // Increment m by k
   m += b; // Increment m.dollars by b
   k += n; // Increment k by n

   std::cout << m << std::endl;
   std::cout << k << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Dollors: 10.45, Cents: 125
Dollors: 9, Cents: 95
```

Comment: Thanks! I do appreciate your help, but there is a small problem. This way I can make it work too. I want to make it work like `a = increment (a,5);` it should grab a and should add it to 5. That's where I'm stuck, or not. Where I stuck is `k = increment(k,m);` exactly this part because I'm failing to get the values from them.

Comment: @TKD. His point is that `a = increment(a, 5);` is better and more idomatically expressed as `a += 5;`, which is the purpose of `operator+=`.